# Find a basis of the image of a linear transformation defined by: $T(a, b, c, d) = a(1 + t + t ^2 ) + b(t + t^ 2 ) + ct^2 + d$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

$T(a, b, c, d) = a(1 + t + t^2) + b(t + t^2) + ct^2 + d$

is a linear transformation. I have no idea how to go about this. Is there a way to do it without using matrices?

$T: C_4 → C[t]_{≤2}$ polynomial

Comment: What is the $t$?

Comment: @Larara it is mapped to a polynomial

Comment: Now I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Check that $1,t,t^2$ are in the range (=image) of $T$, and deduce that this is a basis therein.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Note that

$$T(0, 0, 0, 1) = 1;$$

$$T(1, 0, -1, -1) = 1 + t + t^2 -t^2 -1=t;$$

$$T(0, 0, 1, 0) = t^2.$$